# How to implement an Aggregation in SQL? (This is not about GroupBy)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship, aggregation

In the scope of a university project I am supposed to implement an aggregation of my database.
I'm given a Entity-Relationship model which looks similar to this one:
[image: Example for an Aggregation as a Entity-Relationship model]
Now I'm supposed to implement a SQL-Script which creates a database like this, but I cannot find anything about this topic on google or anywhere else. In the slides of my Professor it says

> - For example, to represent aggregation manages between relationship works_on and entity set manager, create a schema
>     manages(employee_id, branch_name, title,manager_name)
> - Schema works_on is redundant provided we are willing to store null    values for attribute manager_name in relation on schema manages

So I tried to just put two tables into my SQL-Script one called `works-on` and one called `manages`. In `works-on` I put all the Primary keys of `job`, `branch` and  `employee` and defined them as foreign keys. In `manages` I put all of these Primary keys and additionally I put `manager`. Now the problem is that when I use the Reverse-Engineer of MySQL-workbench to create the EER-Model of the database, I don't get anything out of it which has to do with this aggregation. So what am I doing wrong here?
As requested by @Barmar I just wrote the `CREATE TABLE`-statements that I would've used for this:

```
CREATE TABLE job
(jobid INT,
PRIMARY KEY(jobid));

CREATE TABLE employee
(employeeid INT,
PRIMARY KEY(employeeid));

CREATE TABLE branch
(branchid INT,
PRIMARY KEY(branchid));

CREATE TABLE manager
(managerid INT,
PRIMARY KEY(managerid));

CREATE TABLE works_on
(jobid INT, KEY(jobid),
branchid INT, KEY(branchid),
employeeid INT, KEY(employeeid));

CREATE TABLE manages
(jobid INT, KEY(jobid),
branchid INT, KEY(branchid),
employeeid INT, KEY(employeeid),
managerid INT, KEY(managerid));

ALTER TABLE works_on
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_workson_employee FOREIGN KEY(employeeid) REFERENCES employee(employeeid);
ALTER TABLE works_on
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_workson_branch FOREIGN KEY(branchid) REFERENCES branch(branchid);
ALTER TABLE works_on
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_workson_job FOREIGN KEY(jobid) REFERENCES job(jobid);

ALTER TABLE manages
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_manages_employee FOREIGN KEY(employeeid) REFERENCES employee(employeeid);
ALTER TABLE manages
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_manages_branch FOREIGN KEY(branchid) REFERENCES branch(branchid);
ALTER TABLE manages
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_manages_job FOREIGN KEY(jobid) REFERENCES job(jobid);
ALTER TABLE manages
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_manages_manager FOREIGN KEY(managerid) REFERENCES job(managerid);
```

Comment: Show the `CREATE TABLE` statements in your schema.

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this, without telling me what's wrong about the question?
@Barmar This is not the actuall schema that I want to implement, It's just a little easier example. Do you need the `CREATE TABLE` statements for this exact schema or can I put the once that I'm actually using?

Comment: you need to show whatever code you've tried to write that;s relevant to the question.

Comment: @Barmar I just wrote the code for this exact example and added it to the question. Do you think you can help me with it?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. The diagram shows a relationship between `manages` and `works_on`. But the slide doesn't mention anything like that.

Comment: @Barmar that's exactly my problem. I don't know, how to generate this relationship because those to obviously don't have primary keys and the slides are expressing it extremely bad. But the text and the diagram belong together in the in the slides

Comment: I suspect the problem is that MySQL Workbench has nothing to do with ER or EER modeling, despite adopting its terminology. It can only draw table diagrams.

Comment: It may be useful to compare aggregation with associative entity sets / gerunds, which does the same thing but is represented and explained differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ER-Diagram is missing an important information: the cardinality between the manager and the new entity that is built from the other 4 elements `job`, `employee`, `manager`, `branch` and `works-on` (this new entity is marked by the square around them).

From the quote on the slides we can deduce that it is a `0..1`-relationship, 
that means every combination of `job`, `branch` and `employee` (or every entry in `works-on`) has at most one `manager`, but does not require one (in contrast to e.g. a *composition*).

But you will have to verify that cardinality in your actual task.

You can oftentimes implement an ER-diagram in several ways, but the slides imply the following realization:

```
CREATE TABLE manages
( jobid INT not null,
  branchid INT not null,
  employeeid INT not null,
  managerid INT null,
  PRIMARY KEY (jobid, branchid, empoyeeid)
);
```

I omitted the trivial foreign keys to the tables `job`, `employee`, `manager` and `branch`.

With this implementation, you do not have an explicit table for the `works-on`-relation anymore, just like the second statement in your slides says. It is included in the `manages` table. That's only possible for a `0..1`-relation, which is why that cardinality was deducable.

If you want to keep a table for `works-on`, you would use

```
CREATE TABLE works_on
( jobid INT not null,
  branchid INT not null,
  employeeid INT not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (jobid, branchid, empoyeeid)
);

CREATE TABLE manages
( jobid INT not null,
  branchid INT not null,
  employeeid INT not null,
  managerid INT not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (jobid, branchid, empoyeeid),
  FOREIGN KEY (jobid, branchid, employeeid) 
    REFERENCES works_on (jobid, branchid, employeeid)
);
```

Again, I omitted the trivial foreign keys.

To simplify the foreign key (and maybe to emphasize that the combination is considered a new entity), you can, as @Barmar proposed, add an additional (usually auto-increment) key to the `works_on`-table and use this value in the `manages`-table, although the slides do not do this here.

In case you need to implement a `0..n`-relation (several manager can manage a specific `works-on`-combination), you cannot absorb the `works-on`-relation in the `manages`-relation anymore (so you need both tables), and to respect the `n`, you will have to include `managerid` in the primary key, `PRIMARY KEY (jobid, branchid, empoyeeid, managerid)` (but still need to keep the `FOREIGN KEY (jobid, branchid, employeeid)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess this answers my question perfectly.

Comment: But one little question: You understand "redundant provided" as "it's not provided, because it's redundant"? Because I understood it more like "it's provided even though it's redundant". But I'm not a native speaker so I'm just curious here.

Comment: And some more little questions (sorry for the comment spam): Why do you put all the `not null`s here? I thought a primary key automatically can not be null in SQL.

Comment: The sentence should be read as "Schema works_on is redundant, provided we..." or "Schema works_on is redundant, *if* we are willing to store null values" (as done in the 1st version). Redundant obviously means it exists at least twice, so the table might exist; but saying something is redundant also (at least for me) implies that you should get rid of it. If it's not implied, the next bullet on the slide should tell you to remove the table. If you want to keep the `works-in` table (in the first version), you need to make sure that all records are in both tables! Otherwise it would not ...

Comment: be redundant, as records that are in `works-in` but not in `manages` are distinguishable from tuples that are in `works-in` and also in `manages` (with `manager` set to `null`). This would encode some information that is not part of your ER-diagram, so your 2-table implementation (with `null`) would only be correct if you would add e.g. a trigger to update the other table on every change (which is often the case if you need to manage redundant information). About the explicit `not null`s in the statements: they are just for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a primary key to the `works_on` table, and then reference that in the `manages` table, rather than referencing `employee`, `job`, and `branch` directly.

```
CREATE TABLE works_on (
    works_on_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    jobid INT,
    branchid INT,
    employeeid INT,
    CONSTRAINT jobid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES job(jobid),
    CONSTRAINT branchid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES brahc(branchid),
    CONSTRAINT employeeid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES employee(employeeid)

);
CREATE TABLE manages (
    managerid INT,
    works_on_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT managerid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES manager(id),
    CONSTRAINT works_on_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES works_on(id)
)
```

Comment: Is this just the only way that you see, to create a reference between the two relationships `manages` and `works_on` or are you familiar with the concept of an aggregation in an Entity-Relationship-Model and this is the way that you implement this concept in SQL?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really an ERM expert, so maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help. I'll leave this open for a bit to see if there maybe is another solution to it. If not I'll accept your answer tomorrow or smth. It's a really annoying problem, because when you're trying to google for it you either get results showing what an aggregation is in terms of an ERM without SQL implementations or you get things about aggregation functions in SQL...